# ASMX WebService and Dataset

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I'm just trying to play with webServices and I'm having a little problem.

ASP.NET
Visual Studio 2013
SQL Server 2012
C#

I have created a webService that take a ID number and return a list of data. I'm using a DataSet to reurn the data. Everything is working ok (I can see the data in the XML) but there's 2 column that are not displayed in the XML (GameDate and GameTime). GameDate is set as date and GameTime is set as time in SQL.

XML Result

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="Table">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TeamName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="GameDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="GameTime" type="xs:duration" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<ID>2301</ID>
<FirstName>Hamel</FirstName>
<TeamName>Team Bring It</TeamName>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
<ID>3826</ID>
<FirstName>Coté</FirstName>
<TeamName>Team Bring It</TeamName>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
<ID>5017</ID>
<FirstName>Barrette</FirstName>
<TeamName>Team Bring It</TeamName>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
<ID>5549</ID>
<FirstName>Therrien</FirstName>
<TeamName>Team Bring It</TeamName>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
<ID>6763</ID>
<FirstName>Perreault</FirstName>
<TeamName>Team Bring It</TeamName>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table6" msdata:rowOrder="5">
<ID>992</ID>
<FirstName>Poliquin</FirstName>
<TeamName>Renegades</TeamName>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table7" msdata:rowOrder="6">
<ID>1840</ID>
<FirstName>Bouthillier</FirstName>
<TeamName>Renegades</TeamName>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table8" msdata:rowOrder="7">
<ID>2747</ID>
<FirstName>Bouchard</FirstName>
<TeamName>Renegades</TeamName>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table9" msdata:rowOrder="8">
<ID>4096</ID>
<FirstName>Archambault</FirstName>
<TeamName>Renegades</TeamName>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table10" msdata:rowOrder="9">
<ID>5741</ID>
<FirstName>Vivace</FirstName>
<TeamName>Renegades</TeamName>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

C# Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for TestWS
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class TestWS : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public TestWS()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public DataSet getListLigue(int numero)
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB_36624_hlm_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (DataSet dataset = new DataSet())
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspCeduleByPlayer", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p_ID", numero));
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        adapter.Fill(dataset);
                        return dataset;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the definition of stored procedure `uspCeduleByPlayer`

Comment: using datasets makes baby jesus cry

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Your `DataSet`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` all implement the `IDisposable` interface and should therefore be deterministically disposed much in the same fashion you're doing with the `SqlConnection` by employing the `using` construct.

Comment: Also, you're creating *two* `SqlCommands`: the first being `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();` and the second being `cmd = new SqlCommand("uspCeduleByPlayer", conn);` . The first one is overwritten by the second (obviously) and makes the first, unused, object available for garbage collection. Remove it.

Comment: can you write create script of uspCeduleByPlayer?

Comment: I have changed the code to add all using statement like Jesse suggested ... and I guess it was the problem because it's working now !!?? Do I need to put any other information to help the community ?

Comment: @JohnNicholas why using dataset is bad ? What should i use instead ? thanks

Comment: a strongly typed collection, a generic class. Datasets hark back to .net days pre generics. Then when you use array list a lot you didnt care about things being object and having to cast. The result was lots of really irritating bugs to find. However the *very* col thing about statically typed languages is making the compiler do as much work for you as it can. A List<YouEntity> is far preferred. As above asmx is dead, however what you have learnt from it is easily transferable. Use MVC, or wcf if you need a service layer.

Comment: @JohnNicholas thanks for the info. Since my "learning" project was really at the beginning, I have now switched to WCF for my first test and it's working good ;-)